# Парсинг YAML в SQL таблицу с помощью программы Mysql

Tags: mysql, парсер, yaml

Хотелось бы узнать, можно ли и как из файла YAML заполнить SQL-таблицу с помощью только(!) MySQL запросов?

**Пример YAML-файла:**

```
games:
- id: 1
  name: Ships in the ocean
  date: 2021-12-10
- id: 5
  name: ZOO Railroad
  date: 2021-12-09
- id: 14
  name: Octopus-destroyer
  date: 2021-12-10
- id: 35
  name: Ships in the ocean
  date: 2021-12-01
```

**Таблица, которая у меня получилась (SQL):**

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `games`(
    id INT UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    date DATE
);
```

**Запрос, который я делаю (SQL):**

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "pathtofile/file.yaml" IGNORE
INTO TABLE games
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\n'
LINES STARTING BY ':' 
TERMINATED BY '\n-'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

**Результат:**

```
+----+----------------------------+------------+
| id | name                       | date       |
+----+----------------------------+------------+
|  1 |   name: Ships in the ocean | 0000-00-00 |
|  5 |   name: ZOO Railroad       | 0000-00-00 |
| 14 |   name: Octopus-destroyer  | 0000-00-00 |
+----+----------------------------+------------+
```

Нужно, чтобы поля столбца *"name"* не включали в себя *"name: "*, и чтобы записывалась валидная дата.

**Дополнительно**: можно ли выборочно взять поля из объектов для записи? Например, только id и name? (см. пример YAML-файла)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так должно работать

```sql
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "pathtofile/file.yaml" IGNORE
INTO TABLE games
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\n'
LINES STARTING BY ':' 
TERMINATED BY '\n-'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(
  @id,
  @name,
  @date
) SET
  `id` = @id,
  `name` = SUBSTRING(TRIM(@name), 7),
  `date` = SUBSTRING(TRIM(@date), 7)
;
```

Т.е. вначале читаем файл в переменные, а потом уже преобразованные переменные вставляем в таблицу.

> можно ли выборочно взять поля из объектов для записи?

Да. Нужно исключить их из секции `SET`